# VSCode output not printing properly for Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

```
let list = []
for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    list.push({age:i, gender:'male'})
}


for(e of list)
    console.log(e)
```

VS Code output

```
{age: 0, gender: 'male'}
{age: 1, gender: 'male'}
{age: 2, gender: 'male'}
```

No scrolling or anything, just three objects. Terminal works fine.

Comment: @Kinglish Probably all the objects?

Comment: Not really sure if I understand it right. But your goal is to print all of the 20 items in your `list` array. If your question is like terminal level printing, instead of scrolling, I think you can press the `enter` key to view the remaining output?

Comment: @Z Mars I probably  should of added, I'm running Ubuntu. Pressing enter does nothing, when I expand one of the objects in Debug Console I get `No debugger available, can not send 'variables'`